# Query to get user roles in DNN

Tags: sql, dotnetnuke

I need a query to see which Roles users have in DotNetNuke.
I found this query but it gives the RoleID and not the name.
What if there are more than one role associated to a user?

```
SELECT Users.FirstName, Users.LastName, Users.Email,UserRoles.RoleID
FROM UserRoles 
INNER JOIN Users ON UserRoles.UserID = Users.UserID
```

Comment: If there's more than one role with a user, you'll get more than one record for that user. For the other part, you'll need someone who is familiar with the DNN schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the `Roles` table in your query if you want the Role Names.

```
SELECT Users.FirstName, Users.LastName, Users.Email, UserRoles.RoleID, Roles.RoleName
FROM UserRoles 
INNER JOIN Users ON UserRoles.UserID = Users.UserID 
INNER JOIN Roles ON UserRoles.RoleID = Roles.RoleID
WHERE (Roles.PortalID = 0)
```

You also might want to include the PortalID to avoid duplicates from other portals. However I would recommend to use the DNN core functionalities do determine a user role, with the `RoleController`.

Answer (score -1):

If there are 2 roles for a user it will bring 2 rows for the same user with different RoleID. n rows for n roles.